# app stopped when a new theme is applied to the splash Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, android-theme

I've been trying to launch a new activity in my app and, although it does for a moment, inmediately after opening the new screen, the app stops.this things is done when i applied custom theme to splash screen layout.

---

```
com.androchunk.splash_screen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.androchunk.splash_screen, PID: 3656
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androchunk.splash_screen/com.androchunk.splash_screen.Splash_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.androchunk.splash_screen.Splash_Activity.onCreate(Splash_Activity.java:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)  
      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.androchunk.splash_screen:drawable/androchunk" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060054 a=-1 r=0x7f060054}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2596)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2536)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.androchunk.splash_screen.Splash_Activity.onCreate(Splash_Activity.java:13) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
    at com.android.internal
```

Comment: Did you miss this in the LogCat? - `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.androchunk.splash_screen:drawable/androchunk" (7f060054)  is not a Drawable (color or path)`

Answer (score 0):

In the 15 lines，it shows:

`“Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView”`

That means your `ImageView`  has mistakes.

I think it may be caused by the construction method.To write the right custom `Imageview`,you must extend three construction method from the `Imageview`. If you miss one, that will result in mistakes.

In the line：

`“Resource "com.androchunk.splash_screen:drawable/androchunk" (7f060054)”`

It seems that your drawable resource file can‘t be found.

Check that your file is in the right path. Perhaps the file has been put in the wrong resolution like this:

`res/drawable-xxx,res/drawable-xx`

Comment: The question says nothing about a custom imageview

Comment: So i said may be...But,i haven't seen the same question when i use the native Imageview except for the custom Imageview

Comment: I have seen it, and the exception is in the message. `is not a Drawable (color or path)`

Comment: there is no problem with imageview and the drawable before changing theme is show everithing perfectly but when change in Actionbar to noActionbar this will occure.